Need to recover my child google account after it was deleted ( need photos ) back only
Good day
Please assist me my in a stage that I want to cry due to my child account was deleted on her pervious phone that was in for repairs and know the account is not active any more there is 11year of photos on this account and I really need to recover it badly please assist i went through recovery but the account cant be find , i google and checked video but no hope .
This is my hope now
Thanks
